# css - Why is this div not properly placed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried putting a fontawesome fullscreen icon on the bottom of this iframe, but the div it's in (background made green for your convenience) is halfway below the parent div. Here's the code:
HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>funnies</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/204c1cf7c6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="game-frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="75%" height="80%" cellspacing="0" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
   <div id="game-options">
   <b><p class="logo-options">Skool</p></b>
   <div class="icons-options">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-expand" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
   </div>
   </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
}
#game-frame{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border-top: 0.5vw solid black;
  border-left: 0.5vw solid black;
  border-right: 0.5vw solid black;
  border-radius: 1vw 1vw 0px 0px;
}
#game-options{
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0.5vw solid black;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 1vw 1vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.logo-options{
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.icons-options{
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show an image that describes the isssue?

Comment: @KhangTran I would, but it's already answered. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the two elements to be on the same line, then you should set both to have `display: inline-block`.

```css
#game-options > b {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

However, you might want to consider using flexbox instead. In this case, you can remove the display and float properties, then add the following:

```css
#game-options{
  / * other properties */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```